# Peaks in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I am having a hard time visualizing peaks in real analysis.

My first confusion is when looking at a sequence to see whether or not it has a peak. In looking at the sequence
($\frac{n+1}{n})$ my guess is that it has no peaks. I am assuming that this is true since $x_m > x_n$ for all $n > m$.

My second confusion is coming up with examples of a sequence with peaks. For example, finding a sequence that has exactly four peaks. I am not sure how to use the definition to do so.

Thank you!

Comment: ‘Peaks”? This sounds like an informal term. What do you mean, and why do you care about them?

Comment: @FShrike I believe the definition of peak is in the body, that is $x_m$ such that $x_m>x_n$ for $n>m$.

Comment: I think you should graph these sequences out, for example identify your sequence with the points $(n, \frac{n+1}{n})\in \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}\times \mathbb{R}$. Once you see this pictorially, it may be easy to construct a sequence with four peaks.

Comment: @ZackFox I will try that, thank you!